# How many teams at maximum can become champion in the tournament?

Tags: combinatorics

12 teams are playing in a cricket tournament. Two teams play three matches with each other; one in the home ground, one in the opponent's home ground and the third in a neutral ground. Every win counts for 1 point and loss counts for 0 points. Draws are not allowed. The only outcomes are Winnning or losing. The team with the most points is the champion. If more than one team has the same highest point, the are declared the champion jointly.

I know this problem is probably extremely but just help me out here.

First of all I counted the number of games that will be played. ${12}\choose{2}$ * $3 = 198$

Then I figured that *"One in the home ground, one in the opponent's home ground and the third in a neutral ground"* is probably useless information.

Thats all the **"progress"** I made.

Now I am stuck. I need to figure out a way for teams to have the maximum number of points that can be drawn together. I need to also maximize number of drawn teams. I can't think of a way on how to do it. Need help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you found out how many points are on offer ?

Comment: Do you mean that each pair of teams plays $3$ matches, so that each team plays $33$ matches?

Comment: Is there any assumption of transitivity? ie, if team A beats team B, and team B beats team C, must team A beat team C?

Comment: Will any cricket match have a winner or can it end in a draw (cricket is far from well known in this part of the world), if so how many points do the teams get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have clearly stated that draws are not allowed, so in $198$ matches, $198$ total points are on offer.

All $12$ teams can't be champions, as $198$ is not divisible by $12$. However, it is divisible by $11$, so the maximum number of teams that can be declared as joint champions is $\boxed{11}$, which can happen if one team loses all its matches, and thus earns $0$ points.

---

### Addendum to address Henriksupports the community's comments

We can leave out team $12$ as the team that loses all its matches, thus the remaining $11$ teams need $15$ points each. In the table below, the rows indicate points won by team $1\:thru\;11$,

$\displaylines{x2121212121\\1x212121212\\21x21212121\\121x2121212\\2121x212121\\12121x21212\\212121x2121\\1212121x212\\21212121x21\\121212121x2\\2121212121x}$

Comment: There's quite a bit of way from saying that one team loses all of their matches (which gives each of the other 11 teams 3 points) and to describing how 11 teams can end with $\frac{198}{11}=18$ points.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity: It is not clear to me what you are asking, and why (perhaps) you have downvoted. OP has just asked for the maximum number of possible joint champions,, not for describing in detail how it can happen.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthe community: If you are bothered about establishing the **feasibility** of the outcome (though obviously it is  extremely unlikely), it is easily established symmetrically,, I have added an addendum.

Comment: It was exactly the feasibility I was thinking of. It's easy in exercises like these to arrive at some result that cannot be realised, so I thought that was needed.